# how to set bandwidth limitation for tcp communication on localhost

Tags: linux, sockets, bandwidth

I am running C++ client and sever implemented using grpc locally on different ports. What i want to do is to run both of them under different bandwidth so that i can see a difference on the time taken to finish the entire communication.

I have tried wondershaper and trickle, but it didn't seem to work. 
I also tried to use tc to do the traffic control as following

```
tc qdisc add dev lo root tbf rate 10mbit burst 10mbit latency 900ms
```

I tried to use this command to limit the local bandwidth to 10M. Is this the right way to simulate the bandwidth locally?

Comment: "it didn't seem to work". Well then it likely means you did something wrong. But obviously we can't tell you what unless you give details of what you tried to do. `wondershaper` is just a front end for linux `tc`. Linux `tc` is the standard way to do bandwidth allocations so that is the right approach.